# Building for the simulator works, but fails for a device

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors

I added 16,000 words to my `NSArray` and now when I build for the simulator it works, but for a device -- both iPhone and iPad -- it gives me this error:

> Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 Error
>   command/applications/xcode.app/contents/developer/toolchains/xcodedefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how to solve this?

Comment: Is that really the only part of the error?

Comment: bunch of lines saying something is out of range..

Comment: when I reduce those 16.000 words to 6 words it works ..

Comment: There's a non-zero chance that the "bunch of lines" contain information that would be helpful in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something's different between the two builds -- you'll need to figure out what that is.

Note that this is a compile error, not a runtime error. In other words, it's not that something is going wrong during the execution of your program; it's that the compiler can't even build your app in the first place.

Are you specifying the whole array in a method, like:

```
foo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: obj1, obj2, obj3,...,obj16000, nil];`
```

Don't do that. You're giving the poor compiler a headache. Read your data from a file or something instead.

Comment: How is it possible that I can build it on the simulator, I don't understand

Comment: when I reduce the 16.000 words to 6 its works, looks like there are to many words in the NSArray is that possible?